# set a value in react-datepicker dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date

I used react-datepicker. I tried to set the value of react-datepicker from the value which I received as props from another component but either it didn't show the value or it shows a blank page by saying 'wrong time format'.

Datepicker code:

```
this.state = {
  venue_id: props.location.state ? props.location.state.venue_id : null,
  event_start_date: props.location.state ? props.location.state.date : null,
}

<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.event_start_date}
  onChange={this.handleStartDate}
  minDate={new Date()}
  dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
/>
```

I checked the console and found that props were received successfully by the date picker component but still I wasn't able to set the value.

Comment: What is the type of your `event_start_date`?

Comment: It is of type Date. I initialize it with a new Date().

Comment: I also tried to change the format of event_start_date in 'MM/ddd/yyyy' but it also didn't work.

Comment: You need to pass a date object to `selected`. Also, I feel a bit uneasy seeing the usage of `this.state` in your case. Can you try some other variable name instead? This type of usage should only be limited in component constructors only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the event_start_date is not a proper type for selected. There are 2 possibilities:

1. When "props.location.state" returns false, event_start_date is null, which may cause the error.
2. When "props.location.state" returns true, event_start_date takes the value of props.location.state.date, but it maybe not a Date type. You can use `typeof event_start_date.getMonth === 'function'` to find out.

Comment: You are right event_start_date is of type string. I change this to date object and everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to bind selected props of Datepicker to State and change state when you read from database. if you change the date format, u should Parse it to JS date to display.

```
//Date.parse(pass date from db)
setbirth(Date.parse(data['userData']['birthday']))
```